# Executing long command with groovy on linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, groovy, sh

How can I execute a long command with groovy? 
When I execute this command on my linux terminal, I get the correct process id of the process I want. Using groovy I get an empty return. This is what I've already tried:

```
def p = "ps aux | grep 'unit 1' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'".execute()
p.waitFor()
println p.text // this is empty, but it shouldn't
```

How should the correct execution with groovy look like? How do I get the correct process id within groovy?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741065/groovy-process-not-working-with-linux-shell-grep-and-awk-and-ps?rq=1).

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008691/execute-unix-cat-command-in-groovy

Comment: This isn't a duplicate because it contains params with spaces in quotations. That's a difference to the other asked questions on stackoverflow. I already tested the solutions from the other questions without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kinda a duplicate of the 2 questions in the comments, (plus some others I can't find at the moment), but try:

```
def cmd = /ps aux | grep 'unit 1' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'/
def out = [ '/bin/sh', '-c', cmd ].execute().text.trim()
println out
```

Comment: Thank you tim! I got it working with your code and "pgrep -f". Your code also worked directly.

Comment: [This was the other question I was thinking of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823666/getting-the-process-id-of-another-program-in-groovy-using-command-slinging/16858871) that shows how to use Process pipes